# Complete Square Partial Fraction

Tags: calculus

$ ∫ (dx)/(x^2+2x+2) $

So how I started solving the problem this way;

$ ∫ 1/(x+1)^2+1$

I did this because if you tried to break the denominator of $x^2+2x+2$ and reduce it you would get an imaginary number.

Then I substituted for u

u= (x+1)

Then I got dx = $ ∫ (1)/(u^2+1)$ du

$= arctan(u) +C = arctan(x+1) +C$

would this be the right procedure for complete the square?

Comment: Your third line's parentheses is missing a power of two.  And yes, it is correct.

Comment: Easy check - differentiate the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is $\int \frac{1}{(x+1)^2+1}dx$ with $u=x+1$ we get $dx=du$ and our integral is
$\int \frac{1}{u^2+1}du=\arctan(u)+C=\arctan(x+1)+C$